# How can evaluate a recursive solution in matlab?

Tags: matlab, recursion, symbolic-math

Suppose that I have the solution vector

```
conv=(y0,y1,y0+y1,y0+y1+y2,y0+y1+y2+y3);
```

where `y0,y1,y2,y3,y4` are symbolic variables and `y2=y0+y1, y3=y0+y1+y2, y4=y0+y1+y2+y3`. Now, I assign the values `y0=1,y1=1,` and then I would like to evaluate recursively (with a for) the solution. Is it possible?

I could solve the problem making

```
y0=1;
y1=1;
y2=eval(conv(3));
conv(3)=y2;
y3=eval(conv(4));
conv(4)=y3;
y4=eval(conv(5));
conv(5)=y4;
```

But this is not with a for. It is not the best solution (I know it)

I hope that anyone can help me because the real problem is with 130 variables.

Regards

Comment: A for loop? I am confused

Comment: You say that your variables are symbolic, but they're not defined as such in your example code.

Comment: Yes, I loop. Also, the variables are defined as symbolic variable

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your variables as symbolic. Then you can simply use [`solve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html):

```
syms y0 y1 y2 y3 y4
eq = [y0==sym(0),
      y1==sym(1),
      y2==y0+y1,
      y3==y0+y1+y2,
      y4==y0+y1+y2+y3]
s = solve(eq)
s.y2
s.y3
s.y4
```

which returns `1`, `2`, and `4`, respectively.

This system can also be solved numerically using linear algebra with [`mldivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html):

```
A = [1 0 0 0 0;
     0 1 0 0 0;
     1 1 -1 0 0;
     1 1 1 -1 0;
     1 1 1 1 -1];
b = [0;1;0;0;0];
y = A\b
```

If `A` and/or `b` is symbolic, a symbolic linear system solver will be used.

Comment: Give some time to try your answer. Thank

Comment: The problem with your answer is that if I have 130 variables I need to write a lot of code

Comment: @GaboBengo: It sound like you expect magic. Your question didn't involve 130 variables and I have no way of diving what your "real problem" is or looks like. Symbolic schemes are often a poor choice for large problems with many variables and complex equation anyway.